# Git merge - only include conflicts in merge commit, not everything

Tags: git, merge

I have a feature branch with around 100 commits to merge into develop.  I originally tried rebasing onto develop, but this resulted in a lot of the same conflicts coming up repeatedly as each commit was replayed, and I didn't feel like doing `git mergetool` and sorting out the same conflict 100 times.

So I tried a merge instead, with and without `--no-squash`, but the final commit listed *every* changed file between the branching-off point and the merge, essentially one big commit with all changes from both develop, and the feature branch, since they diverged.  Obviously this is no good either, as the changes from the feature branch have to be reviewed.

What can I do?  I'm sure I've used `git merge` before and ended up with a mixed commit history, as opposed to a big merge commit.

The command I'm using is `git merge develop --no-squash`, with the feature branch checked out.

Update: according to the manual, a merge only looks at the commits (so usually the branch heads) to be merged, and the merge base; not the individual histories.  Looks like I'll have to `rebase -i` to get things in order, then try the rebase again.

Comment: why exactly is one big squashed commit not good for you and why wouldn't you follow the standard git merge workflow instead of rebase/squashed one?

Comment: " ... as the changes from the feature branch have to be reviewed"

Comment: there would be loads of irrelevant code mixed in with the code to be reviewed - to be specific, the end diff contained about 30 screens worth of all the code that other devs happened to be working on while my feature branch was in the works - and not all of it in clearly separated parts

Answer (score 0):

If you sit on a `master` and do `git merge --squash workbranch` you should at the end get a diff that will result only in branch + conflict resolution changes.

Comment: Possibly the problem was that I was on the feature branch, merging the master.  I didn't try merging from the master as we just don't do that in our workflow, but maybe I could have done that and then copied the resulting history into a feature branch...

Anyway, I ended up just starting from a fresh branch and checking out files from the feature branch, and writing commit messages as though I was doing the work over again, which turned out OK.